# How do I search for an email that might be in my Spam folder on iphone or ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, email, spam

If I got an email and it may be in my junk/spam folder, how do I search for it in that folder? (Or "how do I search for an email that could be anywhere, including in my junk/spam folder)

Comment: It can be anywhere I think it can be in the spam but what is the spam folder?